# libgdx getHeight() does not cover the whole screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I am new to libgdx and have been practicing using the `ShapeRenderer`. I am trying to place a rectangle at the bottom of the screen but the `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` function is returning a value that does not cover the whole length. If I set the rectangle's coordinates to `(0, screenHeight)`, it only goes halfway down the screen.

Also, when I log the values of the dimensions from the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` functions, they both return 1440.
[This is the rectangle (White section)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLu5G.png) when `width = getWidth()` and `height = getHeight()`.

Code:

```
public class GameClass extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture goalTexture;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private ShapeRenderer shape;
    private ScreenViewport viewport;

    //x-axis length for top/bottom bar
    private float goalWidth = 200;

    //y-axis height for back bar
    private float goalHeight;
    private float goalPostThickness = 20;

    //Screen height and width
    private float screenWidth;
    private float screenHeight;

    //How far down/up posts are from edge of screen
    private float goalPostOffset;



    @Override
    public void create() {


        viewport = new ScreenViewport();

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        shape = new ShapeRenderer();


    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        goalTexture.dispose();
        shape.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        //Logic
        screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        System.out.println(screenWidth);
        System.out.println(screenHeight);

        goalPostOffset = screenHeight/3;

        //Draw
        cam.update();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        shape.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        //Top goal bar
        shape.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shape.rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        shape.end();


    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the code section you posted is a typo. You load the width in the heigth
screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

Comment: I am an idiot. You are a life saver, I have literally been struggling with this all day. Thanks!